Keyboard Issues with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
If my Dell laptop goes into Sleep or Hibernation, when I wake the machine back up the keyboard doesn't work anymore.  I have to restart the machine.  Any guidance on what steps I can make to troubleshoot?

Can you attach an external keyboard and check it it survives a suspend and hibernation?
